# How can I get value of textbox or dropdownlist and send to database in ASP.NET MVC4

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a dropdownlist like this:

```
var Country = new List<ListItem> 
{ 
        new ListItem { Text = "American" }, 
        new ListItem { Text = "British" } ,
        new ListItem { Text = "Spanish" }, 
        new ListItem { Text = "Persian" } ,
        new ListItem { Text = "China" },
        new ListItem { Text = "else" }
};
@Html.DropDownList("Country", new SelectList(Country))
```

When a user choose “else” , one textbox appears and user can type it’s country on textbox, I did this by jquery :

```
@Html.TextBox ("txtCountry",null,new {@id="txtCountry"})
```

I want to define a variable to get Country from user and send to database.
Filed’s name in Model is “Country”

How do this?

Comment: Why do you mean when you say "I did this by jquery"?? did you create the control in jquery with the name txtcountry??

Comment: no, I just appear and hide textbox by jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the list of form controls values using FormCollection Class.
Try the below option

Note : Your controls should have have names (just having an id is not returning values in the formCollection)

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult YourActionMethod(FormCollection Collection)
{
        string Country = string.Empty;

        if (Collection["txtCountry"] != null)
            Country = Collection["txtCountry"].ToString();
//Else you can assign the values to your model object.
        return View();
}
```